# Reflection and Activation in .Net Native

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-native

I have the following code in a UWP app which works fine in Debug mode but throws an exception when compiled in Release / .Net Native.

```
var type = typeof(IHashCommand);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract);
```

The exception that is thrown is:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'The type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshallers.BaseMarshaller' cannot be
>   found in assembly 'System.Private.Interop, Version=999.999.999.999,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

I tried editing the "Default.rd.xml" file and added a namespace node based off of some documentation I found (it didn't work or I'm not setting it up correctly).

```
<Namespace Name="MudLib.HashCommands" Activate="Required All" Dynamic="Required All" Browse="Required All" />
```

Effectivly what I'm trying to do is reflect over all the classes in that namespace that implement the IHashCommand interface and then activate them.

Anyone know what I'm missing or have any direction I should go?

Comment: You may want to split up your one large statement so that you have a better idea what statement results in the exception

Comment: Part of why you're going to have a rough time is that this construct will cause .NET Native to have to do a ton more work (which we might screw up). We're not really well suited for broad runtime reflection directives like this. I'd love to understand the thing you're trying to accomplish, maybe there's a better way. For example, I could imagine that a registration based pattern would make things easier on us. That, of course, would depend on your goal.

Comment: @Flydog57 I split it up, it first fails on "x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x)".

Comment: @MattWhildenMSFT I have a UWP program (basically a specialized telnet app for text based games).  I'm working on sharing the core logic with a WPF version.  My interpreter loads up a set of commands (from these classes) that the user can execute from their command line.  Although most commands are shared between UWP and WPF, some are not due to UWP support.  I was trying to load them all via reflection so it would just know what was there based off of the build target (UWP or WPF).  My work around (what you might be hinting at) will be to use platform directives and manually load these up.

Comment: Got it. Because .NET Native is all ahead of time compiled, there's a pretty heavyweight piece of machinery that tries to determine all the reflection context you'll need at runtime. Loops over all types in all assemblies is particularly stressful for our analysis. Most of the time we do okay but you could possibly avoid the issue by writing down things more explicitly. Sounds like you're on the right track to get unblocked. If you hit other issues you can always contact us at dotnetnative@microsoft.com. Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the explanation, it's appreciated and makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that there is an assembly that is included by `.Net Native`. The name of the assemby starts with *Hidden*. Excluding that assembly will do the trick.

```cs
var searchForType = typeof(IHashCommand);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(assembly => !assembly.FullName.Contains("Hidden") && !assembly.FullName.Contains("Private"))
        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
        .Where(type => !type.IsInterface && !type.IsAbstract && searchForType.IsAssignableFrom(type));
```